# No views in hierarchy found matching: is assignable from class: class android.widget.AdapterView

Tags: unit-testing, android-espresso, android-recyclerview

I am trying to get the recycle view using onData but i am stuck in this error:

> No views in hierarchy found matching: is assignable from class: class
>   android.widget.AdapterView

The code is just this:

```
onData(allOf(isAssignableFrom(RecyclerView.class), withId(R.id.ce_musers_list)))
.check(matches(withEffectiveVisibility(ViewMatchers.Visibility.VISIBLE)));
```

My adaptor extends `RecyclerView.Adapter` as it should for a RecycleView, yet, seams the matcher is looking for a simple Adapter.
This is my first time with espress, so i may be failing in something basic.

My Espresso version is 3.0.0

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`onData()` is used only with the `AdapterView` and its subclasses, which RecyclerView does not belong to.

There is a helper class that espresso comes with: [RecyclerViewActions](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/contrib/RecyclerViewActions) that can be used to perform various actions on a recyclerview and itemviews of the viewholders.

For instance, if you want to make an assertion - you can scroll to the itemview and then use regular `onView()...` to check particulars of that viewholder.

Comment: Let's use [RecyclerViewActions](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/contrib/RecyclerViewActions?hl=en) from androidX instead of the un-maintained package.

Answer (score 1):

```
    val recyclerView = onView(
        allOf(
            withId(R.id.myRecyclerView),
            childAtPosition(
                withClassName(`is`("androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout")),
                0
            )
        )
    )
    recyclerView.perform(actionOnItemAtPosition<ViewHolder>(1, click()))
```

Comment: what is childAtPosition?